# Entity classes created using ADO.NET Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

What is the type of Entity classes created by the Entity Framework which map to the database tables? Are these classes like the classes created using the LINQ to SQL designer and are defined as "partial classes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the `.designer`-file of my `.edmx`-file, eg

```
public partial class City : global::System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject
```

see msdn for more information about [`EntityObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.entityobject.aspx)